# apply() to find closest value in 2 vectors

Tags: r, vector, apply

I have two vectors, and I need to write a code to find the position in the second vector of the value closest to the value of the first vector. I also need it to be pretty computationally efficient, as the dataset will be large, so I'm trying to avoid a loop.

```
 v1 <- c(-.2, -.5, -.12, -.8, -.04, -.9, -.2, -.77, -.3, -.01)
 v2 <- c(-.015, -.06, -.12, -.2, -.3, -.4, -.52, -.65, -.78, -.92)
```

I want a code that will go through values in the first vector and tell me which number of value in v2 is closest to them, so I would want to answer to be:

```
 > answer <- 4, 7, 3, 9, 2, 10, 4, 9, 5, 1
```

I know I could use a loop through the first vector and which.min like so:

```
 for(i in 1:length(v1){
 answer[i] <- (which.min(abs(v1[i] - v2)))
 }
```

This gets me the right answer, but I just want a better/faster way to do this. I think there's a way to use sapply() for this, but I have been looking at it too long and confusing myself. Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sapply`, the option is

```
sapply(v1, function(x) which.min(abs(v2 - x)))
#[1]  4  7  3  9  2 10  4  9  5  1
```

Or with `outer`

```
max.col(-abs(outer(v1, v2, `-`)), 'first')
#[1]  4  7  3  9  2 10  4  9  5  1
```

---

Or using `findInterval`

```
i1 <- order(v1)
findInterval(v2, v1[i1])[i1]
```